# How to do safe inserts using GORM for Mongo's low-level API?

Tags: grails, mongodb, grails-orm

I am trying to do a safe insert using GORM for Mongo's low-level API.

I have reproduced the problem in a clean Grails project like follows:

1. Create a new Grails project
2. Uninstall the Hibernate plugin
3. Install the GORM for Mongo plugin
4. Create a controller with the following action

   ```
   import com.mongodb.*

   class TestController {

       def mongo

       def index = {

           def database = mongo.getDB("ExampleDatabase")
           def collection = database.getCollection("ExampleCollection")

           def document = new BasicDBObject();
           document.put("key", "value")

           collection.insert(document, WriteConcern.SAFE)

           render ""

       }
   }
   ```
5. When firing the action, the following exception is thrown:

   ```
   2011-07-27 12:53:03,161 [http-8080-1] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - Exception occurred when processing request: [GET] /WriteConcern.SAFE-test/test/index
   Stacktrace follows:
   groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: value for class: com.mongodb.WriteConcern
       at com.gmongo.internal.Patcher$__converAllCharSeqToString_closure2.doCall(Patcher.groovy:81)
       at com.gmongo.internal.Patcher._converAllCharSeqToString(Patcher.groovy:80)
       at com.gmongo.internal.Patcher$_converAllCharSeqToString.callStatic(Unknown Source)
       at com.gmongo.internal.Patcher$_converAllCharSeqToString.callStatic(Unknown Source)
       at com.gmongo.internal.Patcher._convert(Patcher.groovy:69)
       at com.gmongo.internal.Patcher$_convert.callStatic(Unknown Source)
       at com.gmongo.internal.Patcher$__patchInternal_closure1.doCall(Patcher.groovy:31)
       at writeconcern.safe.test.TestController$_closure1.doCall(TestController.groovy:17)
       at writeconcern.safe.test.TestController$_closure1.doCall(TestController.groovy)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
   ```
6. If I change the action to use the Mongo Java API as follows:

   ```
   def index = {

       def database = new Mongo().getDB("ExampleDatabase")
       def collection = database.getCollection("ExampleCollection")

       def document = new BasicDBObject();
       document.put("key", "value")

       collection.insert(document, WriteConcern.SAFE)

       render ""

   }
   ```
7. Now it works and the document is persisted to the Mongo database as expected.

My question is this: Is this a bug with the GMongo wrapper, or then how should safe writes be done using the low level API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears due to the GMongo library and how it patches the `DBCollection` object to handle passing of `Map` objects to the `insert` method and converts them. It assumes that all of the arguments of the `insert` method are `Map` objects and will then try to get the `value` property from the `Map.Entry`.

Looking at the [source of Patcher.groovy from GMongo library](https://github.com/poiati/gmongo/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/gmongo/internal/Patcher.groovy#L82) you'll see the function `_convert()` that attempts to do this. It looks like a fork of the Github project with type check on the argument (either to see if it's a `WriteConcern` or to check if it's actually a `Map` before passing to the `_converAllCharSeqToString`) is necessary.

EDIT:

I created a [pull request](https://github.com/poiati/gmongo/pull/4) on Github for the appropriate code change, but as with all things Groovy, patching the class can also help. You can "patch" the `WriteConcern` class in your `BootStrap.groovy` to have a `getValue` method and that will allow you to pass the parameter in:

```
def init = { servletContext ->
    com.mongodb.WriteConcern.metaClass.getValue  = { null }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Monkeypatching the WriteConcern class like you said works great.